# JAVA JNA: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) after multiple successful calls of the same native C .dll libraries

Tags: java, exception, shared-libraries, jna, jvm-crash

I'm using a java-based modelling platform and I'm currently trying to solve ordinary differential equations (ODEs). The platform I'm using provides 2 wrapper functions:

1. providing integrated access to any of the numerical solvers from
   apache.commons (which are all nonstiff solvers)
2. providing native access to a non-stiff solver (i.e. CVODE
   from the SUNDIALS package) written in C from 2 shared libraries (.dll)

While the first option provides no difficulties and runs as expected, the second option results in an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) crash **after already running several successful calls of the native solver** (full error log was too long so you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/aJAGkajv))

I've created a small example of 3 simple ODE's which are reset to their original conditions after a threshold is reached. The output is correctly plotted here:
[image: simple ODE]

While the first option continues running until I manually stop the process, the native solver crashes after an apparently random amount of integration steps.

I'm really in need of successful access to this native solver because I have a more complex problem that requires the stiff solvers it provides.

I'll also provide a list of reasons that are definitely **not** causing it

- no hardware failure (memory has been diagnosed to confirm this)
- I tried running the platform both from within eclipse and without
  eclipse, so I don't think it's eclipse
- The C libraries are widely used and most definitely correct
- both my .dll libraries, my java and my operating system are 64 bit
- not enough memory (I tried both 3 Gb and 14 Gb, both crash)

sadly, it is virtually impossible for me to provide a reproducible example code as the modelling platform (i.e. GroIMP) as well as the native solver libraries are quite complex (and not my own code).

The question is obviously what could be causing these crashes and what I can try to resolve them or investigate the problem in a more detailed and constructive manner.

Comment: If the failure is not deterministic, try disabling garbage collection to see if that might be involved.

Comment: Based on your crash dump, the failure happens during GC of callbacks.  This isn't happening during JVM shutdown, is it?

Comment: you may be on to something here, by adding -Xms14000M and -verbose:gc I noticed GC does not get initiated and as a result, it no longer crashes. However, is this indicating some fundamental flaw in my approach, as larger application will definately require GC.

Comment: Are you using a lot of callbacks?  If you're not using them explicitly, does your native library define structs with function pointers?  Normally a `CallbackReference` is generated for any Java `Callback`s you instantiate and pass in to native code as a function pointer.  Is there any chance native code might have tried to free that memory?  Or overwritten the memory `CallbackReference` allocates in order to store its native stuff?

Comment: I'm no expert but I assume a lot of callbacks are being made. Basicly the wrapping solver function is written in java but uses functions from the native library to solve it, so during integration, these functions are constantly called. I looked into the native library documentation and I found: " CVodeCreate creates an internal memory block for a problem to be solved by CVODE. If successful, CVodeCreate returns a pointer to the problem memory. This pointer should be passed to CVodeInit.  If an initialization error occurs, CVodeCreate prints an error message to standard err and returns NULL.

Comment: I believe the function CVodeCreate is the only function being created as a function pointer, but it is being called by nearly all other native methods

Comment: Can you include in your question the flow of control, including where function pointers (native or Java) are involved?

Comment: I'm afraid that would be a very tedious task and it will take me a while to figure out the flow of calls. However, your inputs have already proven very useful and I'll try to do some further problem solving on my own. I'll get back to you if I find new info. Thanks!